# Just cannot get redmine to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redmine

So, I've been trying to get redmine to work with following all kinds of tutorials around the web, but I always get stuck at the same step :

```
G:\Ruby187\apps\redmine>rake db:migrate
NOTE: SourceIndex.new(hash) is deprecated; From G:/Ruby187/apps/redmine/config/.
./vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100:in `new'.
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Looking up the error, they tell me to change the Rakefile line :

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

to

```
require 'rdoc/task'
```

But then I get the error :

```
G:\Ruby187\apps\redmine>rake db:migrate
NOTE: SourceIndex.new(hash) is deprecated; From G:/Ruby187/apps/redmine/config/.
./vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100:in `new'.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rdoc/task

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is some information about my setup :

1. Machine : Windows 7 (32-bit)
2. Redmine Version : 1.1.2
3. Tutorial Followed : http://www.ptperalta.net/index.php/technology/installing-redmine-on-windows-step-by-step-guide.html
4. gem list :

G:\Ruby187\apps\redmine>gem list

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.4.2)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2)
```

Please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your version of rake - from the [RedmineInstall](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Requirements) requirements section:

> **Rake 0.8.7** is required (rake 0.9.x is not supported by Rails yet)

You'll need to uninstall the currently installed version of rake:

```
gem uninstall -v=0.9.2 rake
```

(answer `y`)

and install an older version:

```
gem install -v=0.8.7 rake
```

See also [this](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/24163?r=24827#message-24827) message on the redmine forum

Answer (score -1):

If you get stuck installing Redmine "by hand" on Windows, try [BitNami Redmine Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) (contains Redmine plus all required dependencies, in one single Windows installer).

I didn't manage to install Redmine manually either, so I used the BitNami installer, and it just worked, without any problems.

Comment: I fail to see how installing from Bitnami is a solution.

Comment: Because you don't have to do [all of this](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache) by yourself (I wasn't able to get it to work). Instead, you run one installer and then everything *just works*.

Comment: That is not a solution to the problem stated, it is a workaround.

Comment: Depends on your point of view. To me, the actual problem is "I've been trying to get redmine to work" and this question is just about an implementation detail. I had the same "get redmine to work" problem, and I solved it by using the Bitnami installer.

Comment: I agree with tgunr: the point is to learn what caused the problem and how to fix it rather than avoiding it by using a blackbox pre-installed image.