# Redmine installation Issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am trying to install redmine on my localhost, i got some issue in the middle of installation

```
C:\redmine>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rak
e/rdoctask.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/task.rb:30: warning: already ini
tialized constant Task
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Gem::SyckDefaultKey

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

then i found some post [Just cannot get redmine to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485299/just-cannot-get-redmine-to-work)

I uninstalled `gem uninstall -v=0.9.2 rake` and installed `gem install -v=0.8.7 rake` and ran the following command `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"` . still i am not able to proceed further.

```
C:\redmine>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rak
e/rdoctask.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/task.rb:30: warning: already ini
tialized constant Task
rake aborted!
A key is required to write a cookie containing the session data. Use config.acti
on_controller.session = { :key => "_myapp_session", :secret => "some secret phra
se" } in config/environment.rb

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

what i done wrong on this?

Comment: The output posted suggests that rake 0.9.2 is still present - are you sure it did uninstall correctly? (gem list)

Answer (score 1):

You must generate the secret code for session before deploying env.

Juste use this command:

```
rake generate_session_store
```

and then you can continue with your:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
```

and finally (under Windows):

```
rake redmine:load_default_data RAILS_ENV="production"
```