# Redmine: rake error when installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

When I try to install redmine by following the procedure here:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

At step 4, I receive the following error:

```
xxx@xxx.com [~/rails_apps/redmine]# rake generate_session_store
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate_session_store'
```

Can you help me to solve?
Some infos:
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.13
RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
RAILS VERSION: 2.3.14

Comment: Since I've CPanel, I followed this other procedure to install redmine: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails so I replaced the default folder "redmine" to the redmine 1.3.2. Now, I'm still stopped on the fourth step, but with another error: "NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/stileweb/rails_apps/redmine/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Gem::SyckDefaultKey" PLEASE HELP

Comment: Is the file being referenced from the previous install? If so it may be conflicting: remove the folder and install from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.** is a warning message.
You can ignore it.

Regarding the error: **Don't know how to build task 'generate_session_store'**

Just make the following file exists **~/rails_apps/redmine/lib/tasks/initializers.rake**.

If not, make sure you've download all the files.
Also, you always need to run the rake task inside the redmine folder.

```
[~]# cd ~/rails_apps/redmine
[~/rails_apps/redmine]# ls
[~/rails_apps/redmine]# =1.6  app  config  db  doc  extra  files  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  lib  log  public  Rakefile  README.rdoc  script  test  tmp  vendor
[~/rails_apps/redmine]# rake generate_session_store --trace
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
** Invoke generate_session_store (first_time)
** Invoke config/initializers/session_store.rb (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute generate_session_store
```

If you want to make the **rdoc message** to go away you can do the following:

- If you have redmine's trunk version, edit ./Gemfile and add the following line:

  gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2

And then run **bundle install**.

- If you have the latest stable *1.3.x* version copy **additional_environment.rb.example** to **additional_environment.rb** and add the line suggested by *RobinGower*:

```rb
config.gem "rdoc", :version => "3.12"
```

And then run gem install -v "3.12"

Comment: To avoid touching the Gemfile which will probably change on future versions, you can do the following:<br/>

    RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/generate redmine_plugin extensions<br/>
    echo 'gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2' > vendor/plugins/redmine_extensions/Gemfile

Comment: Ah! I'd assumed that the rdoc gem was providing the rake task.

Comment: The Gem::SysckDefaultKey error is due to a bug on rubygems version 1.8.13 [issue #250](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/250). Try updating it to version 1.8.14: `gem update --system 1.8.14`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to update that gem: `gem list rdoc` will tell you what versions you have installed and you'll want `gem update rdoc` if you've not got version 2.4.2 or above. If you have got it installed (and rails isn't using it), you may need to add something like this to `config/environment.rb`:

```
config.gem "rdoc", :version => "3.12"
```

You can, of course, replace "3.12" with which ever version number you have.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the rdoc version is 3.12, I added the line you suggested. However, how to restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

The installation documentation states:

> **Rake 0.8.7 is required** (rake 0.9.x is not supported by Rails yet)

And from your question I get that you're using 0.9.2.2.

You'll need to uninstall the currently installed version of rake (use `gem list` to get the exact version number you have installed):

```
gem uninstall -v=0.9.2.2 rake
```

and install an older (supported) version:

```
gem install -v=0.8.7 rake
```

See also [this answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485299/just-cannot-get-redmine-to-work/7488528#7488528)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had already done what you said, but the result was always the same. Seems like CPanel overwrite something.