# Redmine installing problems Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, rake, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine based on Official Wiki, but when I try to run `rake generate_secret_token` the following error shows

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate_secret_token'
```

I already went into this question with no success

[Redmine: rake error when installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997784/redmine-rake-error-when-installing)

** For the problem above, I believe running the command `rake secret` has resolved, cause no generate_secret_token is listed when I call `rake -T` **

And when I try to run RAILS_ENV=production rake `redmine:load_default_data` I get

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'redmine:load_default_data'
```

Following is the trace:

```
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rak /task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rake generate_secret_token` ?

Comment: ya ... same error ... edited my question and added the trace

Comment: check if rake is working at all `bundle exec rake -T`

Comment: it seems to be .. after that command it gave m a list of options to run ... I tried `rake about` and it gave me versions of the environment Ruby, Gem, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At end I solved my problem installing Bitnami's package for Redmine http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine

Comment: actually this is not the answer, the error you got you want to install Redmine and self configured and me trying too,
and installing Remdine though package Bitnami is not a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The `generate_secret_token` task is only available for Redmine >= 2.0.0. If you use an older version (which seems likely), the related task is called `generate_session_store` As such, try

```
bundle exec rake generate_session_store
```

Comment: I believe that I'm using Redmine last version > 2.x ... how could I confirm it?

Comment: Running this command didn't resolve it .. anyway ... I just discovered Bitnami and using it to build a redmine server ,..

Comment: That solved it for me! I _thought_ I was looking at the "Upgrading for 1.x" page but in fact there was a redirect to "Upgrading for 2.x" page.. :-( so this was exactly my problems.. Thanks a lot!